# SDL Shows blank window like it has crashed

Tags: c, sdl

When i build my program, i get this output:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zdq5.png][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zdq5.png%5D%5B1%5D)

here is the code for creating the window:

main.c:

```c
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "RenderWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0)
        printf("ERROR: %s",SDL_GetError());
    if(!IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG))
        printf("ERROR: %s",SDL_GetError());
    CreateWindow("M64!", 1280, 720);
    int gameRunning = 1;
    SDL_Event event;
    while(gameRunning == 1){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                gameRunning = 0;
        }
    }
    cleanUp();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is RenderWindow.h:

```c
#ifndef RENDERWINDOW_H
#define RENDERWINDOW_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
int CreateWindow(const char* title, int p_w, int p_h);
int RenderWindow();
void cleanUp();
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;

#endif
```

And here is RenderWindow.c:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "RenderWindow.h"

int CreateWindow(const char* title, int p_w, int p_h)
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, p_w, p_h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window == NULL)
        printf("ERROR: %s", SDL_GetError());
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    return 0;
}
void cleanUp()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

Is this a software issue, or is it a hardware one? cause my PC is pretty old.

Edit:This is solved, for anyone having the same question the answer to this is is that you have to write: `SDL_RenderClear(your_renderer);` and `SDL_RenderPresent(your_renderer);` where the first one clears the renderer, and the second one updates it

Comment: Try to run the program from the command line. Commonly error messages appear via `stdout`.

Comment: If you read the code you might have noticed that i have error printing things, also my build system does run thourgh the command line

Comment: OK, my fault. And is there any output? Or what do you expect instead? (Please add new information by [edit]ing your question.)

Comment: Oh nevermind, asked on a sub reddit and someone gave me the answer, thank you for trying to answer tho! :)

Comment: Then please write your own answer or delete the question. Putting "{anything}" in the title is **not** the way SO works. You might like to take the [tour] again. ;-) Have a nice day!